# No IDLE for Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I installed Python 3.1 yesterday on my Windows Vista PC, and was surprised to find that the version of IDLE is 2.6.4, for "Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"

I was hoping to use IDLE to investigate some of the new features of Python 3...

I guess I'm stuck with the command line...

Anyone know what's up with Python 3's IDLE?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Got it! I changed the Target of the shortcut to   "c:\Python31\pythonw.exe" "c:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyW"   (with the quotes), and now the shortcut (and shortcut key) open version 3.1.1 of IDLE. Idea was from the 1st answer to the question at [How to start IDLE (Python editor) without using the shortcut on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118260/how-to-start-idle-python-editor-without-using-the-shortcut-on-windows-vista)

Comment: I just realized that 
C:\Python31\pythonw.exe "c:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyW"
is actually the correct form (C:\Python31\pythonw.exe needs no quotes). I found that in executing the shortcut Vista actually stripped those quotes!

Answer (score 3):

Type 'idle3' in the terminal window. That should launch your copy of idle 3.1

Comment: The OP already found a solution to his (very localized) problem nearly **four** years ago. Your answer does not add any value.

Comment: This response just help me. The time between question and answer didn't seem to matter. +1