# Start IDLE with Python 3 on Linux (Python 2.7 installed alongside)

Tags: python, python-3.2, python-idle

I initially had Python 2.7, which often comes bundled with the OS (currently using [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 12). I wanted to try Python 3, so I installed it alongside Python 2. All is fine there, and I can run both versions in the terminal by calling either `python` or `python3`.

However, there doesn’t seem to be any way to start IDLE with Python 3. Is there some flag that I can pass to IDLE when I start it so that I can pick which version of Python I would like it to run?

E.g. (these don't work),
`idle3` or `idle --shell=python3` or something like that. I read about pointing to a different executable in [this question about IDLE for Python 3 (on Vista)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630728/no-idle-for-python-3). However, I can't seem to do the analogous thing on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to install the appropriate package - Python 2.x and 3.x aren't compatible with each other.

You can find the link [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/idle-python3.1).

Comment: Thank you for that. I found the exectubale for idle in `/usr/bin`, one called `idle`, and another called `idle-python2.7`. So I tried `sudo apt-get install idle-python3.2`, and guess what? Problem solved!

Answer (score 13):

Just type `sudo apt-get install idle3` in your terminal and IDLE for your version of **Python 3** previously installed will be installed.

Then both are compatible. You run the 2.7 IDLE from your terminal by just typing `idle`. And you run the IDLE 3 version by just typing `idle3` in the terminal. That worked for me.

Comment: Short and sweet. It worked! Though the resulting executable for Python 3 using `sudo apt-get install idle3` was not `idle3`, but `idle` (at least on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)). It launched as IDLE 3.6.9 (Python 3.6.9), *"Python 3.6.9 Shell"*. It didn't install an executable by the name `idle3`: *"Command 'idle3' not found"*

Answer (score 3):

I had to install *python3-tools* to get *idle3* (using [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) 18).

Comment: Works on Fedora 17 also.

Answer (score 2):

I installed IDLE using the following command:

```
sudo yum install python-tools.x86_64
```

And I can run both commands, and it gives me a Python 2 or Python 3 shell, respectively:

```
idle
idle3
```

Answer (score 1):

[Christy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856802/start-idle-with-python-3-on-linux-python-2-7-installed-alongside/17553333#17553333):

> "I had to install *python3-tools* to get *idle3* (using Fedora 18)."

sudo yum install python3-tools

This also works on [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) 19.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Python 2, you can install it by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```

And in the case of Python 3 you can install it by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Re *"This works fine for me."*: On what system? Linux? What distribution?`[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)? What version?