# Invoking Python IDLE on Linux

Tags: linux, python-idle

I am trying to set up a Python development environment. I have Python 2.7.3 running on Linux Mint 14. I downloaded IDLE and installed it. It clean installs and Python runs just fine.

So how do I invoke IDLE? There isn't any IDLE in my path: `which idle` returns nothing. `man idle` returns nothing pertaining to an editor. Nothing in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. Calling `idle()` inside the Python interpreter doesn't work. Invoking `python` brings up a shell, not IDLE. No menu entry for IDLE in Linux. No import library named IDLE that Python can find. Three O'Reilly books consulted and not a word about invoking IDLE in Linux. YouTube videos of Python favor Windows, not Linux. Web searches have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please keep questions here limited to one topic (IDLE or ERIC).  Also, keep in mind that not everyone here is a gentleman.  You also don't mention which Linux distribution you are using

Comment: Ned, Single question noted. Perhaps you could suggest an appropriate salutation. Line 2: Mint 14. Thanks, Pete

Comment: After getting acclimated here, you'll notice that a salutation is neither needed nor preferred.

Comment: A text editor, an interpreter, and thou. ;)

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): *[Start IDLE with Python 3 on Linux (Python 2.7 installed alongside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856802/)*. But isn't there an older canonical question?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not familiar with Mint myself, but since it claims to be [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-based, try installing the `idle` package:

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```

That should pull in all the appropriate packages for the installed version of Python.  Then you should just be able to start IDLE with:

```
idle
```

in a terminal window.

Comment: and idle3 for python3

Comment: @fzzylogic: [Not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856802/start-idle-with-python-3-on-linux-python-2-7-installed-alongside/14132374#comment133279196_14132374). It depends.