# How can I install IDLE for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-idle

I have already installed Python 2.7 in the Linux system (distribution [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint)), and now I want to install IDLE for Python 2.7 with the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```

But it does not work, returning the error:

> Unable to fetch some archives

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: post your full error. Isn't there any thing before(just a bit before) or after 'unable to fetch some archives'?

Comment: Similar questions: *[Start IDLE with Python 3 on Linux (Python 2.7 installed alongside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856802/)* and *[Invoking Python IDLE on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097795/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try installing it again.