# How can I run IDLE for Python 3 in a Conda environment?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-idle, conda

For running Python 2, all I do is activate the required Conda environment and just type *idle*. It automatically opens IDLE for Python 2.7.

But I can't figure out how to do this for Python 3. I have Python 3.5 installed in my environment. I used `conda create -n py35 anaconda` for installing Python 3.5.

Comment: at least in windows, I found the idle command not good enough for me, so I make a direct access to classic idle with this destination: `C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"`. Maybe something similar may work for you

Answer (score 12):

For how to open IDLE from a Conda virtualenv, the process that works for me is:

```
activate myenv
python -m idlelib
```

This should open up the IDLE editor and you can run code within `myenv`.

Answer (score 6):

Type *idle3* instead of *idle* from your [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Idle for python 3 is simply called idle.exe in the /scripts directory now.

Comment: @chrisfs: [The same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856802/start-idle-with-python-3-on-linux-python-2-7-installed-alongside/14132374#comment133279196_14132374) for some versions of some Linux  distributions: `idle`, not `idle3`, for launching IDLE 3. Using idle3 results in *"Command 'idle3' not found"*

Answer (score 5):

To install another version of Python (e.g., Python 3.5.2), when using Anaconda for one version of Python (e.g., Python 2.7), you can do the following on the Anaconda prompt:

First, create a new Conda environment and install Python 3.5.2 with anaconda:

```
conda create -n py352 python=3.5.2 anaconda
```

Once complete, if you want to access IDLE of Python 3.5.2 quickly on Windows:

- Go to the `"C:\..Anaconda\envs\py352"` folder in [Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer)
- Create a shortcut for `pythonw.exe` file located on that folder.
- Move the shortcut to your Desktop or any other location easily accessible
- Right-click the shortcut, go to *Properties*, and change the target field in the *Shortcut* tab from

  ```
  C:\....\Anaconda\envs\py352\pythonw.exe
  ```

  to

  ```
  C:\...\Anaconda\envs\py352\pythonw.exe "C:\...\Anaconda\envs\py352\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"
  ```

Comment: For me this does start idle but it doesn't have the right path for all the DLLs that are installed into that Anaconda Env.  So some imports fail.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer for creating a shortcut did not work for me, but I was able to get this to work:

- Create your Conda environment if you haven't already.  I'll call mine `my_env`.
- Navigate to the `C:\...\Anaconda\envs\my_env\Lib\idlelib\` directory
- Create a shortcut for `idle.bat`
- Move the shortcut to another location, rename it, and pin it as desired.