# Python off a Flash Drive, how to start IDLE?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.x, usb-flash-drive

I was trying to run Python 3.3 off of my flash drive. I already tried Portable Python, but most of what it had wouldn't open, and it crashed my laptop.

So, I deleted it, and installed regular Python. Then, I wanted to start adding my favorite modules. And, I needed a way to start IDLE without the original shortcut.

To install modules, I added my Python install to my PATH variable.

To make all this easier, I made a batch file, using some code I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118260/how-to-start-idle-python-editor-without-using-the-shortcut-on-windows-vista).

So far, I have this. It also asks for the drive letter, because that changes from computer to computer.

```
@echo off
echo This only works if your Python install is added to the system-wide PATH variable
set /p Path="Enter the Drive Letter on this computer. No Symbols, Just the Letter, Capital"
cd %Path%:\Program Files\Python33
echo type this when python comes up...
echo import idlelib.PyShell
echo idlelib.PyShell.main()
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
python
```

It outputs this:
[image: IDLE Bringer Output]

If you go on and follow the instructions and type what it says, it brings up IDLE.
I couldn't figure out how to get the batch file to actually type into the Python prompt, so I told it to tell the user to type what needed to be typed.

What I need to know is, how can I change the PATH variable from within the batch file. Also, how to I remove it when I'm done (this isn't as important, and could even be in a separate batch file).

Or, alternatively, is there a way just to shortcut to IDLE?

Also, is there a way to run .py files without the command line, with the Python install on my flash drive?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry....I'm in school, and I haven't had time to try this yet. I will accept and/or upvote once I can actually try the different solutions....

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Revisited a year later and realized I forget to accept... fail =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke Python with this command line:

```
python -c"import idlelib.PyShell;idlelib.PyShell.main()"
```

and it will bring-up IDLE shell without the need for the user to type anything.

**Edit:** BTW, Are you sure you really *need* to change the global path settings. Try to see if the following script can start Python the way you want. You must put it in the root of the USB drive where you have your Python installation.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
:: Removes trailing backslash (for readability in the following)
set SCRIPT_DIR=%SCRIPT_DIR:~0,-1%
set PYTHON_HOME=%SCRIPT_DIR%\Program Files\Python33
set PATH=%PYTHON_HOME%;%PATH%
"%PYTHON_HOME%\python.exe" -c"import idlelib.PyShell;idlelib.PyShell.main()"
```

**Edit:** Every process has an associated *environment*, which is a set of name-value pairs called *environment variables*. When a process is started it gets a copy of the environment of its parent process. The global OS settings for environment variables are used for processes started directly from the OS (GUI or command line) shell. The `set` command in batch files sets or modifies an environment variable in the environment of the current process (not globally).

All the `set` commands you see in the above script change only the environment of the current process. These changes will be seen by the process created by the last line (`python.exe`) because it is a *child process* of the command shell (`cmd.exe`) process that is executing the batch-file.

The line

```
set PATH=%PYTHON_HOME%;%PATH%
```

prepends the content of the `PYTHON_HOME` variable to the `PATH` variable of the current process. For example, if `PATH` were `c:\foo\bar;d:\aaa\bbb` and `PYTHON_HOME` were `c:\python` then the new value of `PATH` will be `c:\python;c:\foo\bar;d:\aaa\bbb`

Comment: So this will bring CLI Python without editing the PATH variable?

Comment: It should. At least it works on my system, but I rarely use Python nowadays and I tested it only superficially. It brings up the IDLE shell, but I didn't try if all expected Python features are working properly. Test it yourself and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: What do these do? `set SCRIPT_DIR=%SCRIPT_DIR:~0,-1%
set PYTHON_HOME=%SCRIPT_DIR%\Program Files\Python33
set PATH=%PYTHON_HOME%;%PATH%`? Doesn't that last bit edit the PATH variable? Or is that a user-created separate PATH variable?

Comment: From what you ask it seems that you don't know really what environment variables are (and `PATH` is just an env var with special meaning for the OS). I suggest you google around or search on SO or Wikipedia about that. See the next comment for a very short explanation. BTW, did my post address your problem?

Comment: You're right; I don't really know what environment variables are; all I know is that you need them for python. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can not be guaranteed this is possible unless you have high enough system privileges that you can change the global path. There is really no way around this on most computers that you do not own, which I imagine is the main purpose. In those cases when you have enough privileges (it is worth a try some systems still allow this for regular users but many others do not) you can use:

```
setx PATH "%path%;yourpath"
```

**edit and ps:**

You can figure out the drive letter without input, if you know the disk label, with something like this:

```
@echo off
set label=DRIVENAME
set cmd=WMIC logicaldisk WHERE volumename^^="%label%" GET caption


FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN ('%cmd% ^| find ":"')DO set pydrive=%%G

echo %pydrive%\pathtopython
rem do your stuff here
```

the idle started inside the batch will inherit path but other instances will not. Hard to test conclusively tough.

Explanation of the batch script above. The command *wmic* is short for windows management instrumentation commandline. One can use WMI to do many things one of them is to issue WQL (SQL for WMI) queries as if windows would be a a database. Databases contain many tables in this case the computer is instructed to fetch the table named **logicaldisk**. Table **logicaldisk** has 38 columns and one row for each disk connected to the system. This is way to much data for this purpose. So the data is filtered. *WHERE* causes the database only to spit out rows that contain some specific value in this case its only interested in rows where column volumename ins equal to DRIVENAME, likewise you could use serial number size or any other criteria. Lastly *GET* is used to limit the columns you get back as results since your only interested in the letter name of the drive that's what you ask. That is called a caption in the table so that what you ask.

Since the command is a bit long, so i put the command inside a variable (not the result) this shortens the for line so it fits stack overflow. Since = need to be escaped i need to use the escape sequence ^ too times so it still es capable in the for loop.

The for loop is used to capture the return value of the wmic command. Since the answer has many lines i filter for only the lines which contain a colon character. And put it to variable pydrive.

Comment: What do these lines do? I think I get the rest of it:                                                `set cmd=WMIC logicaldisk WHERE volumename^^="%label%" GET caption`


`FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN ('%cmd% ^| find ":"')DO set pydrive=%%G`