# running python program in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to paste my code from my text editor into the IDLE window, but when I do the program won't run.  Is there a way to run my program without copying and pasting into the IDLE window.  (I'm a complete NOOB)

Comment: Did you take indentation in account when you pasted your program? Python needs a correct indentation!

Comment: I believe there is a button on IDLE that says "RUN." It will run your program.

Answer (score 1):

To run a Python 3 program in IDLE, from the command line:

```
$ python3 -m idlelib -r your_script.py
```

For earlier Python versions, see [How to start IDLE (Python editor) without using the shortcut on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118260/4279)