# How to open as python file as .py instead of .pyw while trying to edit with IDLE

Tags: python-idle

Whenever I right click a .py file and select "EDIT with IDLE" I get the idle.pyw version instead of idle.py. The idle.pyw is giving me issues while running virtualenv and so I just want the idle.py version. Does anybody have any idea how to change the default behavior of which idle version opens when using the right-click edit option?

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118260/how-to-start-idle-python-editor-without-using-the-shortcut-on-windows-vista

Comment: Not quite, I'm able to manually open the idle.py file and then open my script from the already running idle. I would like it so that when I right click on a .py file and select the "Edit with IDLE" option that idle.py is the default. Currently idle.pyw is the default.

Comment: Windows file context menus are defined and controlled by entries in the Windows registry.  However, the main difference between idle.pyw and idle.py is running with pythonw.exe versus python.exe.  The latter will also open a console window, which might or might not solve your virtualenv problem.  You might try renaming idle.pyw to idle.pyw.back and copy idle.py to idle.pyw and see what difference that makes.